# how to calculate epsilon of mpf_class

Tags: c++, c++11, gmp

I try to improve a c++ programm by using the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library).

There is a counter variable that periodically will be increased by a result of a calculation of type double.
The addition happens inside a ISR (interrupt service routine) because of this it should be fast.

Until now the counter variable is of type double which causes a problem.
Some devices (running since years) reach a point where each addition fall under absorbtion so nothing happens anymore.
Other devices already start to discard smaller additions.

Because this it is time to improve it by using mpf_class instead double.
But in order to set the size of the mpf_class properly i need to know the ε (epsilon).

My question is: How can i calculate the epsilon of a mpf_class object?

An example(c++) of this calculation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The mpf type in GMP does not offer an exact radix-2 representation. The requested precision is rounded up by the number of bits in the underlying array element and then at least one additional element is added. If you request a precision of 53 on a typical 32-bit system, the actual values are calculated with between 65 and 96 bits. (Technically, the mpf type is using radix 2^32 arithmetic in this case).

I would recommend looking at the MPFR (Multiple Precision Floating point with Rounding) library instead. It uses the GMP library for the underlying computations but provides more predictable behavior. The use of MPFR is recommended by a note in the GMP documentation.

Comment: ok it is not important for me to know if my system use more memory. I am interested in the biggest possible epsilon. I just need to check whether it meets the requirements. Beside mpfr is installed, i can use it if i have to do so. Provide a solution for mpfr would be fine.